# Convert 2 spaces to tabs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was editing a project, as I have been for months, and randomly only one of my files converted all of its tabs into two spaces. I use "4 spaces" for my tabs, now this one single file decided to become 2 spaces. How can I fix this and convert this file back to 4 spaces? It is only affecting this file, all other files still use 4 spaces.

---

This thing is just buggy. It is now back to 4 spaces and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to settings (`CTRL+,` or `CMD+,` on Mac) and search for 'detect indentation'.

Play around with that setting as well as with the Tab Size setting. When you're done, go to your file, select all content (`CTRL+A` or `CMD+A` on Mac), unindent everything (`SHIFT+TAB`), then open the command pallete and search for 'Reindent'.

Click the 'Reindent Lines' option and see where it gets you.

Also, check if you have a `.vscode` folder in your project. It may contain settings that override your global vscode settings.